# Process values from list of database record-objects to create a new with corresponding data?

Tags: python

With a list of example objects:

```
[<Object object_id = '1' name = 'A' second_name = 'A'>
<Object object_id = '2' name = 'B' second_name = 'B'>
<Object object_id = '2' name = 'B' second_name = 'C'>]
```

where `second_name` have a value belonging to `name` - is a relationship in the database (`second_name = 'B'` and `C` belongs to `name = 'B'` which in turn belongs to `object_id = '2'`, so this is one of the new objects I try to create).

Sorting on `object_id`:

```
record_set = set() # to decide unique objects
for obj in object_list:
    record_set.add(obj['object_id'])

for obj_id in record_set:
   for obj in object_list:
       if obj_id == obj['object_id']:
           # ?
```

I'm not too familiar with the library tools or programming techniques to efficiently create a new object that represents the relationship here. Could someone help me get going?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: @enke No, this is record-objects created by fetching data from a database using asyncpg/SQL.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question? For sorting you might be interested in using the python built-in `sorted`, like `sorted(object_list, key=lambda obj: obj.id)`

Comment: @deponovo It is about logic and/or some unknown (to me) programming technique. I could probably have made it easier by fetching the data in a different way, but this is in general for learning purposes.

Comment: The prob is that it is not clear (at least to me) what you want to achieve. In other words, what is exactly your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your objects seem to be classified in "categories" : they are meant to be grouped on the `object_id` and/or the `name`. So here is a demo :

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from dataclasses import dataclass


# defining a class to reproduce your example, using `dataclass` because it is convenient for an example
@dataclass
class ExampleObject:
    object_id: str
    name: str
    second_name: str


# defining a dataset corresponding to your example
example_data = [
    ExampleObject("1", "A", "A"),
    ExampleObject("2", "B", "B"),
    ExampleObject("2", "B", "C"),
]

# creating the data structure to hold your objects
objects_by_id_and_name = defaultdict(list)  # a dictionary whose values will be lists
for obj in example_data:
    key = (obj.object_id, obj.name)  # I choose to use the couple <object_id + name> as a key
    list_of_key = objects_by_id_and_name[key]  # fetching the list corresponding to this key
    list_of_key.append(obj)  # adding the object to the list


# pretty-printing the result
for key, list_of_objects in objects_by_id_and_name.items():
    print(f"{key=!r} {list_of_objects=!r}")
```

and the result :

```
key=('1', 'A') list_of_objects=[ExampleObject(object_id='1', name='A', second_name='A')]
key=('2', 'B') list_of_objects=[ExampleObject(object_id='2', name='B', second_name='B'),
                                ExampleObject(object_id='2', name='B', second_name='C')]
```